# Emacs 26.1 configure script doesn't like the gnutls version on a RedHat sytem

Tags: build

Even though gnutls-devel.x86_64 is installed on my RedHat 6.6 system.  How do I guide the configure script to the required libraries?

[update 2018-06-03 after hint from Ian]
In fact configure found the libraries but in config.log it says that the library is too old.

Now I'm trying to compile GnuTLS 3.5.18. but it's configure script says that it requires Libnettle 3.1. (whatever this is).

So I'm trying to compile a package called nettle 3.4. which is supposed to include libnettle libs. This configure script runs through but when I'm doing make it says: cd: tools: No such file or directory!

Basically I'm stuck at this stage, what can I do to investigate this mess further?

Comment: Some suggestions maybe here: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/NEWS.26

Comment: @Ian: Hmm, NEWS says it requires version 2.12.2 of Gnutls. I will check which version is installed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install `pkg-config`.

I met same trouble in Ubuntu 1804 on Windows Subsystem for Linux.
I read configure script, and found the script uses `pkg-config` to check version of gnutls.

Comment: Can you provide a link to `pkg-config`?

Comment: after run 'apt-get install -y pkg-config', the issue is resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the mess you found yourself in, I compiled emacs 26.1 on CentOS 6.5 by doing: `configure --with-gnutls=no`

Comment: This is also suggested by the configure script! But is no solution for me I need gnutls for the package support and https pages in eww.

Comment: What does gnutils provide?
I might just fall back to 25.x instead if that works. So does anyone have a path forward on this to get emacs to cleanly compile with the default configure? gnutils should able to be built and upgraded without too much problem.